# Illustrator: Rotate transformed group of objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, transform

I want to rotate an object with a live transform/array effect applied to it.

The object is grouped to a path, which I need as a guide for the rotation. When I rotate this, instead of rotating the group with the path, every individual object is being rotated.

How can I rotate the path and all of the objects rotate as a whole?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the Effect a second time.

If you choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` again you will get a popup stating *"This will apply another instance of this effect."* Then explaining how to edit the existing effect.
 <sup>(which is wrong - only takes a single click in the Appearance panel, *not* a double-click)</sup>

[image]

Just click <kbd>Apply New Effect</kbd>. 
This second effect instance will rotate the entire previous effect as a single object.

This can make for some deep diving if the need to adjust anything arises — due to base objects sometimes being located *nowhere* near where the effect moves the visual preview. But it *will* keep the Effects live.

---

Another option...

Draw a **no-fill**, **no-stroke**, (hollow) rectangle (or any shape) on top of the original effect iterations. **This "hollow" object will be the basis for any transformations.** So, you will want to ensure you place it in a logical position - like at the visual center of the original effect.

Select the "hollow" shape and original effect object and **Group** them - `Object > Group`. Now apply `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to the *group* and everything should rotate as a single object (group)

This method **may** offer a bit more control over the rotation, provided the "hollow" shape is placed in a good position. In addition, locating the object(s) in the future can be less "wild" than the first method above can be.

---

Other than this, you would need to **Expand Appearance**.